# Issues between GSAP pin and rotation

Tags: javascript, css, web, frontend, gsap

Here is my code, please help. I want the text to be rotated, when I rotate the text with css, the rotation resets as soon I add the "pin: true" and when I try to rotate the text with gsap, it doesnt work at all..

```
gsap.fromTo(".text1", { 
  opacity: 0,
  rotation: -18
   
}, 
{ opacity: 1, 
  rotation: -18,
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: '.beyond',
    start: 'bottom center',
    end: '+=80%',
    scrub: true,
    markers: false,
    pin: true
  }
});
```